# Getting TypeError: Cannot perform 'get' on a proxy that has been revoked Redux toolkit

Tags: javascript, redux, redux-toolkit

I'm trying to retrieve data from my local sqlite database and populate redux state with certain values, my reducer is as follows

```
    getItems: (state) => {
      try {
        useKnex
          .select()
          .table("itemTable")
          .then(async (data: any) => {
            state.push({
              itemId: parseFloat(data.itemId),
              itemCode: data.itemCode,
              itemDescription: data.itemDescription,
              itemSellingPrice: parseFloat(data.itemSellingPrice),
              itemType: data.itemType,
              createdAt: data.createdAt,
              updatedAt: data.updatedAt,
            });
            console.log(data);
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.error(`Error: ${err}`);
          });
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    }
```

and on my content page I used useEffected to get the data for testing purposes:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(queryItemsAction());
  });
```

But when I run everything I get:

```
Error: TypeError: Cannot perform 'get' on a proxy that has been revoked
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In redux generally, you *must not* have any side effects in the reducer - what's happening here is that you are triggering a side-effect that runs and will try to write to the store outside a reducer later on (which breaks another rule of redux).

If you have side-effects like this, you'll need to handle that in a middleware. Commonly, thunks are used for this - please read [Redux Essentials, Part 5: Async Logic and Data Fetching](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-5-async-logic)